# How to run a project in QT C++ by another project?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, console, widget

Please accept my apologize in advance if my question is very low level!

I have a project in Qt c++ (QT Widget application). I want to have a button in my project (App) that by pressing this button, another project in another directory (e.g. a Console project) starts to run. Indeed, the directories of my projects differ from each other.
I want to know, is it possible to run my console project by a widget project while these projects are not in the same directory? If yes, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to ask that you want to launch another console app from your GUI app? The question is not clear

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a GUI app. I want to launch a console project in another directory by using a button in my GUI app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `QProcess`.

```
execute(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments)

execute(const QString & program)
```

For example:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString file = QDir::homepath + "/file.exe";
process->start(file);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess it would work. I will try it and inform you about the result.

Comment: I'm still waiting for your result, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QProcess for launching another executable. Find the details [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess it would work. I will try it and inform you about the result.

Comment: Hi again, as I told, I am going to open a console project (name.Pro) by using my GUI. I think QProcess method just works for launching executable files and does not work for mu case. Do you have any idea how to open .pro file by my GUI?

Comment: You need to be more specific. I am not getting clarity on your goal from your question. Why do you want to load a project from your program. A project file(*.pro) is used usually by an IDE like QtCreator. What are you trying to achieve by loading the project file to your GUI application? Please be more clear so that we can help you.

Comment: I have some console projects that each one is developed for a particular task. I am working on a GUI to control all these projects (for example changing parameters in these projects and also control when to run each one). It is not possible for me to integrate all these projects in one directory (GUI's directory). Hence, I am forced to run these projects through their current directories, which differ from each other.

Comment: It will be a difficult task to mimic an IDE. There are lots of components involved like qmake, moc, gcc/cl if you are using QtCreator. From what I understood from your comment, I would suggest that you can create a GUI app for editing the pro files of your different projects and then later compile them separately by invoking qmake on your projects files from your GUI program. But if I were you, I would have done it with shell scripts with some custom qmake variables, instead of a full fledged GUI app.